# Setting repository location on SVNKit's SvnGetStatus

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I need to get the current revision of a local working copy.

So far I've come up with this: (**EDITED**)

```
private static long resolve(File workingDirectory) throws SVNException {
    SvnOperationFactory svnOpFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
    SvnGetStatus svnGetStatus = svnOpFactory.createGetStatus();
    svnGetStatus.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromFile(workingDirectory));
    svnGetStatus.setDepth(SVNDepth.EMPTY);
    SvnStatus status = svnGetStatus.run();
    return status.getRevision();
}
```

I can't find a place to actually specify the location of my working copy, not even in the documentation.

How can I tell SvnGetStatus where to look for the working copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting it as the [*target*](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc2/SvnOperation.html#setSingleTarget%28org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnTarget%29) of the operation:

```
svnGetStatus.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromFile(wcLocation))
```

Comment: That still returns the revision as `-1` just like with no target set.

Comment: @j0ntech You need to `run()` the operation and then fetch the revision number out of the response that `run` returns - `getRevision()` on the operation itself just gives you the revision number you passed as a parameter to the operation (or didn't pass, in this case, hence -1).

Comment: @j0ntech you should probably `setDepth(SVNDepth.EMPTY)` first so it just fetches the status for that particular item rather than recursing into all the descendants.

Comment: Okay, I didn't think of actually running the operation. I've modified it (see the edit), but now the `SvnStatus` object is null, `run()` returns nothing.

Comment: @j0ntech you may be better off using `SvnGetInfo` (the equivalent of `svn info` on the command line) rather than `SvnGetStatus` - by default the "status" operation doesn't return anything if the item you're asking about has no uncommitted changes.

Comment: @IanRoberts is right, "status" reports only locally changed files and directories. Use SvnGetInfo instead.